# Elastica search in different languages

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I want to index the word "jogging" and want to be able to search for the german translation "laufen" or "rennen". Is that possible with ElasticSearch/Elastica?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you send the text of the document through an automated translation engine (eg. google's or bing's) and then index the result of that as a separate document.